# WinRM cannot process the request - Controlled by policy server

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, powershell-remoting, winrm

I have a script to enable basic auth for the ansible control node to connect to windows host. Below is the script, when I execute the script I get an error msg `The config setting Basic cannot be changed because is controlled by policies.`

```
Set-Service WinRM -StartMode Automatic
Set-Item -Force WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic $True
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
```

When I execute the script I get the below error msg

```
Set-Item : The config setting Basic cannot be changed because is controlled by policies. The policy would need to be
set to "Not Configured" in order to change the config setting.
At C:\Users\krishna_venkata\Desktop\test.ps1:2 char:1
+ Set-Item -Force WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic $True
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand

WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = The config setting Basic cannot be changed because is controlled by policies. The policy would need to be set to "Not Configured" in order to change the config setting.

Error number:  -2144108406 0x8033808A
Cannot change GPO controlled setting.
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = The config setting AllowUnencrypted cannot be changed because is controlled by policies. The policy would need to be set to "Not Configured" in order to change the config setting.

Error number:  -2144108406 0x8033808A
Cannot change GPO controlled setting.
```

This is the current winrm config

```
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = false [Source="GPO"]
    Auth
        Basic = false [Source="GPO"]
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = false
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = *
    IPv6Filter = *
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true
```

Comment: Take a look at these 2 links: 1.) https://lonesysadmin.net/2017/08/10/fix-winrm-client-issues/ 2.)

https://serverfault.com/questions/841689/changing-winrm-settings-from-script 

It seems like this should fix your problem